# How can I get more verbose TLS certificate errors with MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, ssl, tls-1.2

When attempting to connect to MariaDB from a remote client (command line on another server), I get the rather unhelpful:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'mydomain.com' (using password: YES)
```

I know this isn't an authentication failure, because if I disable `require_secure_transport = on` in the MariaDB configuration file on the server I'm connecting to, I can log in remotely with this same user and password, from the same remote client.

So there is a TLS certificate issue causing the "Access denied" message.

But it's very hard to know what to look for without details of why the certificate check is failing.

In a browser like Firefox, when there is a certificate issue, it gives you details such as:

1. The certificate expired on DATE.
2. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.
3. The certificate is not trusted because it is signed by a CA that is not in the browser's root store.
4. The certificate is not trusted because the client sees the server as `somedomain.com` but the certificate is issued for the common name `otherdomain.com`.
5. Also, are Subject Alt Names being checked?

It seems like there should be a way to turn on these details in the logs. But all I see on the server is the same access denied message without any TLS failure reason details.

Can I get this information out of MariaDB somehow so I can see exactly why the certificate isn't being trusted by the client?